# How much aid does Palestine receive from the US?

Tags: palestine, foreign-policy, foreign-aid

How much aid does Palestine receive every year from the US? I'm looking for unbiased sources, because a pro-Israel source will likely overstate it and a pro-Palestine source will likely understate it.

Comment: I edited your question to avoid making the issue about your petitions.

Comment: Re: your "defund Israel" - you **are** aware that a large chunk of that "funding" is in military aid that is contractually obligated to be spent on buying products from US military-industrial complex and thus contributing to US GDP, right? :)

Comment: @DVK: that is irrelevant. Cost versus benefit.

Comment: @Jack - the benefit of raising the GDP is a benefit for anyone but an accountant :)

Comment: @DVK Military spending tends to have lower fiscal multipliers, and Israel needs to spend only 75% of our aid on US goods. There are a number of good reasons to fund Israel, fiscal multipliers aren't one of them.

Comment: @Avi - and military spending has non-monetary benefits as well (keeping a vital production line occupied and thus available when domestic demand for that product picks up. Plus, those donations to politicians' PACs from military industrial complex won't pay themselves).

Comment: @DVK Sure, though I think the primary benefit here is increased security for us and for Israel. I think if you want to make a good fiscal argument though, you could likely argue that the $3 billion a year we credit Israel is a hell of a lot less than we spend ourselves to fight terrorism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to a [report](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/mideast/RS22967.pdf) from the Congressional Research Service, the US has given an average of $400 million or so per year in an economic support fund, and around $100 million per year in security assistance funds, since FY2008. (In FY2015, it's $370M in economic support, $70M in security assistance; the numbers are skewed high by abnormally high aid in FY2009, and other years have seen around half the aid of that year). Economic support aid is distributed partly by USAID via vetted contractors, and partly directly to the Palestinian Authority under waivers issued by the President (the waiver numbers fluctuate a lot year-to-year, but have totaled $900M under Obama's administration as of 2014; this is taken out of the economic support fund). So, the average is around $500M/year in aid administered by the US.

In addition, the US is a major contributor to the U.N. Relief and Works Agency for Palestine Refugees in the Near East (UNRWA), giving around $250M/year to them. Add that in, and an average is in the ballpark of $750M/year, with some fluctuation (but that's around the amount; more details are in that report).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. Very unbiased, factual, and no political propaganda involved. I tried to upvote you, but I don't have enough of a reputation. When I do, I'll come back and give you your due credit.

Comment: Straightforward answer, and I like the mention of the UNRWA. +1

Comment: This doesn't seem to include private charitable giving (whether that's in scope for the question is not clear to me)

Comment: @DVK: what private charities do is a lot harder for the people to have a say in, and does not affect US tax dollars. Charitable contributions, whether to Israel or Palestine, are still voluntarily paid by the people who contribute.