# How much international aid does the Palestinian Authority receive?

Tags: international-relations, palestine, middle-east

I'm interested in all money which goes to the Palestinian Authority, from Western countries or otherwise.  Also, how much international aid goes to the West Bank through other channels (like UNWRA or funds dedicated to specific projects)?

Comment: Do you include aide from Iran and such or only official Western channels?

Comment: I'm interesred in all money which goes to the PA. Can those non Western aids be reliably estimated?

Comment: @DavidHerskovics - I cleaned up the question a bit.  Feel free to edit if there's anything else you want to add or if I got anything wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The two most important "*sponsors*" of PA would be US and EU, [according to UNRWA.](http://www.unrwa.org/sites/default/files/Top%2020%20Donors%20to%20UNRWA%20in%202010%20-%20Overall%20Contributions.pdf)

From:

- USA: USD 216,386,867 (US dollars). More info about the US aid you will find in the answer: [How much aid does Palestine receive from the US?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/7979/how-much-aid-does-palestine-receive-from-the-us)
- EU: USD 151,566,702
- Saudi Arabia: USD 93,737,454,
- Sweden: USD 54,439,768,
- Germany: USD 53,061,050,
- Norway: USD 34,595,162,
- Japan: USD 28,836,915,
- Switzerland: USD 23,267,282,
- Australia: USD 22,445,260,
- Netherlands: USD 20,049,472
- Denmark: USD 18,638,884
- Kuwait: USD 17,000,000,
- France: USD 12,852,039,
- Italy: USD 10,714,805,
- Belgium: USD 10,271,039 and,
- Other countries;
- Other banks and NGOs.

**TOTAL**: USD 1,091,649,846.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now: what is that 294,023,401 dollars at the top?

Comment: That's a mistake I made. And fixed.

Comment: The first line is still very confusing. It's only 216,386,867 dollars so 216 millions, not 216,386,867 millions.

Comment: Are you sure you have counted correctly? When I sum your numbers I get 767,862,699 or about $768 million. I also think you have mixed up your numbers so that some include aid going to UNRWA and some doesn't. The PA and the UNRWA are completely different.